# Problem with Snapping

Tags: vertices, edges, snapping

So, I'm working on this house with oblique walls.

I can't properly make the vertex just move along the Y axys and snap to the lower line, as it snaps along the Y axys but doesn't stop exactly ON the line.

Any easy way of doing this? Since I'll have to do it a lot of times.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender allows you to set a custom orientation for transformations, but, unfortunately, does not provide custom orientations for snap projections.

However, if you enable the [Mesh:TinyCAD](http://zeffii.github.io/mesh_tiny_cad/) add-on, (included in 2.78) it will do what you need, and some more.

Comment: Thanks man! It really did the trick. Still find it weird that Blender doesn't have a similar function though.